# Deploy on heroku with s3 does not show images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]I deployed my educational app in heroku(https://slobodalibrary.herokuapp.com). I've set s3 as a storage. But after some time images still disappear. What is the priobem? Where should I dig to fix it?

Comment: Where are you images saved and how do you link to them?

Comment: @luissimo Look at the app source https://slobodalibrary.herokuapp.com you should see that images pathes are correct. But image thumb yuotube that I posted yesterday is not shown now

Comment: @anti-k your upload looks ok .

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like it is finding the image, but doesn't have read access, try this:

> Go into your s3 bucket and make sure that your folder has read access
>   to all.

Comment: Well the log says 404 not found so either you are linking to the wrong image(e.g .png instead of .jpg), or the image doesn't exist in your app.